# Asterisk in method definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking through the `urllib.urlopen` method and I saw this in its definition.
What is meant by this?

```
def urlopen(url, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
            *, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None):
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It makes the arguments after the `*` only able to be used as keyword arguments, this is because the * will absorb excess positional arguments. Google search for keyword only arguments

Comment: Ok got it.  Its a duplicate question. Closing this now.  Thanks